# Generic Association with generic fk: Can't get rid of overlap warning

Tags: sqlalchemy

In a database that I have no control over I have what I believe is a [Generic Association](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) using generic foreign keys. In short: A CommunicationInterface belongs either to a Router or a Server, never both. There's no discriminator because `id`s are unique over the entire database.

Code shortened for brevity:

```py
class Server(...):
    __tablename__ = 'server'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)

    interfaces = relationship(
        'CommunicationInterface', backref='server',
        primaryjoin='Server.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )


class Router(...):
    __tablename__ = 'router'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)
    interfaces = relationship(
        'CommunicationInterface', backref='router',
        primaryjoin='Router.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )


class CommunicationInterface(...):
    __tablename__ = 'communicationinterface'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column('_parent_oid', Integer)
    
    overlaps = 'router,server'
    router = relationship(
        'Router', back_populates='interfaces', overlaps=overlaps,
        primaryjoin='Router.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )
    server = relationship(
        'Server', back_populates='interfaces', overlaps=overlaps,
        primaryjoin='Server.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )
```

Even with the overlap parameter this still gives me warnings like the following:

> SAWarning: relationship 'Router.interfaces' will copy column router._oid to column communicationinterface._parent_oid, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'CommunicationInterface.server' (copies elb_server._oid to elb_communicationinterface._parent_oid). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards. The 'overlaps' parameter may be used to remove this warning.

Is there a better way to declare these relations? And if not, am I using the `overlaps` parameter wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you faced has a few reasons:

- Mixing of `backref` and `back_populates`

  - `backref` also creates a `relationship` on the other side
  - `back_populates` expects a `relationship` on the other side
- `overlaps` incorrect missing on the `relationship` on the other side

This should solve your problem:

```py
class Server(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'server'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)

    
class Router(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'router'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)


class CommunicationInterface(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'communicationinterface'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column('_parent_oid', Integer)
    
    router = relationship(
        'Router', backref=backref('interface', lazy='subquery', overlaps='server, interface'),
        primaryjoin='Router.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )
    server = relationship(
        'Server', backref=backref('interface', lazy='subquery', overlaps='router'), overlaps='router',
        primaryjoin='Server.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )
```

Or if you want to do it with `back_populates`:

```py
class Server(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'server'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)

    interface = relationship(
        'CommunicationInterface', back_populates='server', overlaps='router',
        primaryjoin='Server.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )

class Router(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'router'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    interface = relationship(
        'CommunicationInterface', back_populates='router', overlaps='server, interface',
        primaryjoin='Router.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )


class CommunicationInterface(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'communicationinterface'

    id = Column('_oid', Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column('_parent_oid', Integer)
    
    router = relationship(
        'Router', back_populates='interface',
        primaryjoin='Router.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )
    server = relationship(
        'Server', back_populates='interface', overlaps='router',
        primaryjoin='Server.id == foreign(CommunicationInterface.parent_id)'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me though. The `backref`/`backpopulates` mixup happened during troubleshooting. Maybe relevant: in reality I have one more entity pointing to `CommunicationInterface` besides `Server` and `Router`. Also, what's the logic for the `overlaps` parameter? You seem to use `'server, interface'` in one but only `router` in the other.

Comment: I accepted this answer because I finally got it to work thanks to this. The only thing missing seems to be the `overlaps='server, interface'` parameter in the `router` relationship (not in the backref) in your first example.

Comment: The overlap definition is in my opinion a little bit vague. But it looks like it is related to the order of definition. I’ve looked in the code base a during the table object evaluation the new relationship is compared with the overlap parameter. It took me some trial and error to get it right.